# bash/shell pathname expansion for mkdir, touch etc?

Tags: shell, wildcards

So doing something like this in `bash` and most other shells won't work to create multiple subdirectories or files within subdirectories...

```
mkdir */test
touch */hello.txt
```

There are of course many ways of actually doing this, my preferred one is to use `find` when possible rather than using a `for` loop, for readability mainly.

But my question is, why do the above not work?
From what I understand it's because the full destination file/path does not exist but surely that's a good thing if I'm trying to `mkdir` or `touch`. I've always just moved on and never really questioned it.
But does anyone have a decent explanation for this that will help me understand once and for all?

Answer (score 8):

The point that you may be missing – that many people have trouble with,
especially if they have experience with other operating systems before they come to *nix
– is that, in many other OSs, wildcards on the command line are normally passed
*to the command* to process as it sees fit.  For example, in Windows Command Prompt,

```
rename *.jpeg *.jpg
```

Whereas, in *nix, in order to simplify the job
of the programmer(s) of the individual commands (e.g., `mv`), wildcards
(when not quoted or escaped) are handled by the shell,
in a manner that’s independent of the interface and functionality
of the command that the wildcards are arguments to. 
Most programs that take filenames as command-line arguments expect those files to exist
(yes, `mkdir` and `touch` are exceptions to that rule,
as are `mkfifo`, `mknod`, and, to a partial extent, `cp`, `ln`, `mv`, and `rename`;
and there are probably others),
so it doesn’t really make sense for the shell to expand wildcards
to names for files that don’t exist. 
And for the shell (and, by that, I mean *every* shell –
Bourne, bash, csh, fish, ksh, zsh, etc…) to handle the exceptions differently
would probably be too much of a hassle.

---

That said, there are a couple of ways to get a result like what you want. 
If you know what the wildcard is going to expand to,
and it’s not long, you can generate it with brace expansion:

```
touch {red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet}/rgb.txt
```

A more general solution:

```
sh -c 'for arg do mkdir -- "$arg"/test; done' -- *
```

---

[Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151042/80216) helped me find another way
to do it in bash.

```
benbradley=(*)
mkdir "${benbradley[@]/%//test}"
```

Obviously `benbradley` is just an identifier here; you can use any name
(e.g., any single letter). 
It took me a couple of tries to get this right, so let me break it down:

- `identifier=value`
  creates a (scalar) variable named `identifier`
  (if it doesn’t already exist) and assigns the value `value` to it. 
  For example, `G=Man`. 
  You can reference a scalar variable with `$identifier`;
  for example, `$G`, or, more safely, as `${identifier}`. 
  For example, `$Gage` and `$Gilla` may be undefined,
  but `${G}age` is `Manage` and `${G}illa` is `Manilla`.
- `identifier=(value1 value2 … )` creates an array variable named `identifier`
  (if it doesn’t already exist) and assigns the listed values to it. 
  For example,

    ```
    spectrum=(red orange yellow green blue indigo violet)
    ```
  or
    ```
    all_text_files=(*.txt)
    ```
  `$name`
  will reference the first element (and so is fairly useless). 
  You can reference an arbitrary element as
  `${name[subscript]}`
  ;
  for example,
  `${spectrum[0]}`
  is
  `red`
  and
  `${spectrum[4]}`
  is
  `blue`
  . 
  And you can use
  `${name[@]}`
  and
  `${name[*]}`
  to reference the entire array.

So, here it is in pieces:

    ```
    "   ${   benbradley[@]   /   %   /   /test   }   "
    ```

- `${parameter/pattern/string}`
  expands `${parameter}` and replaces the longest match
  of `pattern` with `string`.
- If `pattern` begins with `#`,
  it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of `parameter`. 
  If `pattern` begins with `%`,
  it must match at the end of the expanded value of `parameter`. 
  In other words,

    ```
    %(the-rest_of_the_pattern)
    ```
  acts like
    ```
    (the-rest_of_the_regex)$
    ```
  (yes, that seems a little backwards). 
  So a
  `pattern`
  that is just a
  `%`
  is like a regular expression that is just a
  `$`
  –
  it matches the end of the input string (search space).

- And I’m using a `string` of `/test`. 
  So this replaces the end of the parameter with `/test`
  (i.e., it appends `/test` to the parameter).
- Another thing about
  `${parameter/pattern/string}`
  that’s non-intuitive is that it ***always*** ends with a `}`. 
  It need not, and ***cannot***, end with a third `/`. 
  Therefore, a `/` in *`string`* cannot be interpreted as a delimiter,
  and therefore we can have a *`string`* of `/test`
  without needing to escape the `/`.
- If `parameter` is an array variable
  subscripted with `@` or `*`,
  the substitution operation is applied to each member of the array in turn.
- When you reference an array as `${name[@]}`
  (rather than `${name[*]}`) and put the results in double quotes,
  you preserve the integrity of the elements of the array
  (i.e., you preserve spaces and other special characters in them)
  without combining the separate elements into one long word.

Answer (score 3):

The wildcard pattern is expanded by the shell before the command is invoked. See [G-Man's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150916/bash-shell-pathname-expansion-for-mkdir-touch-etc/150992#150992) for a full explanation.

Most shells require some form of intermediate command in order to apply a text transformation to the matches. Zsh offers a way to transform matches on the fly with its [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers):

- `e` or `+` to execute code for each match, which can change the match by modifying the `REPLY` string (or even change the number of matches by modifying the `reply` arrray)
- `:` followed by a [history expansion modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) to apply some build-in transformations

Examples:

```
mkdir */(:s:/:/test:)     # takes advantage of the fact that each match ends with /, which it replaces by /test
mkdir *(/e:REPLY+=/test:)
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured out how to do something similar in bash.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because the shell tries to expand the *entire* string `*/test` which doesn't exist yet. By default the string then expands to itself. If you're using Bash you may want to look at the various [globbing options](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#Options_which_change_globbing_behavior) to handle this the way you want.